# Multiple names for the same perl named regex extraction

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I'm working a regex written by someone else. I need to have an existing named extraction aliased to use a different name.

Basically the chunk of the regex I'm working with looks like this:

```
(-|(?<objectname>.*\\(?<process>[^\r\n\\]+))
```

This matches up to a part of a log, containing a path to an executable.

Which pulls out the content that I need into objectname, and the executable name minus the path into process.

I need to alias `objectname` to also be returned if I look for `objectID`. I'm not looking for the /j operator for multiple groups with the same name.

Comment: Why would you ever want to use 2 capture groups around the same bunch of constructs ? Really a bad idea. If your torn between 2 names, get creative.  `IdName`

Comment: @sln, the reason is this is actually used inside of logarithm. I need to retain the original feeling for the rules written by the company to function, but at the same time I need my alias to work for custom developed rules due to a product limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the named capture in another named capture group:

```
(-|(?<objectID>(?<objectname>.*\\(?<process>[^\r\n\\]+)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a simple way to do this!